# twig - building array in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

is it possible to iteratively fill a twig array with values?

```
{% for question in questions %}
{% set multipleChoiceArray = [] %}
    {% for multipleChoice in question.multipleChoiceAnswers %}
        {% set multipleChoiceArray = multipleChoiceArray|merge( multipleChoice.answerText )  %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

the problem is here `multipleChoiceArray|merge(multipleChoice.answerText)`

when i try to pass an array for example with key = loop.index like

```
{% set multipleChoiceArray = multipleChoiceArray|merge({"loop['index']":"multipleChoice['answerText']"})  %}
```

it works but the array contains the strings "["loop['index']":"multipleChoice['answerText']"]"

when i try to pass variables like :

```
{% set multipleChoiceArray = multipleChoiceArray|merge({loop.index:multipleChoice.answerText})  %}
```

exception is : A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("punctuation" expected with value ":")

so i am not able to "push" a value "multipleChoice.answerText" into "multipleChoiceArray"

any hints how that is possible ? 
i just want to gather all possible answers and later check if answer is in that array and count sth up and display

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The argument of merge has to be an array or object to merge it with an existing one. So write it as an array with one element.

```
{% set multipleChoiceAnswerText = multipleChoice.answerText %}
{% set multipleChoiceArray = multipleChoiceArray|merge([multipleChoice.answerText])  %}
```

Comment: this throws an exception : A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "["

Comment: yeah set is very ninja. you can also assign an array of objects to a variable with set and then loop through them. {% set cameras = { "family1": firstArray, "family2": secondArray }%} {% for identifier, item in cameras %}