# Creating an array within for loop with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to create an array and store values in it within for loop but failed so far. How can I do it with Twig?

I've read these but being new in Twig makes it hard to convert into my case.

- [Twig for loop and array with key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299202/twig-for-loop-and-array-with-key)
- [How to set array value in twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113197/how-to-set-array-value-in-twig-template)
- [twig - building array in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841206/twig-building-array-in-for-loop)
- And many more

**PLAIN PHP LOGIC IS THIS:**

```
foreach ($array as &$value)
{
   $new_array[] = $value;
}

foreach ($new_array as &$v)
{
   echo $v;
}
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED WITH TWIG:**

```
{% for value in array %}
    {% set new_array = new_array|merge([value])  %}
{% endfor %}

{% for v in new_array %}
   {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is OK if you define the `new_array` as array before the first loop: `{% set new_array = [] %}`.

Comment: `Twig` is a wrong place to define your application logic

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved by following *Vision*'s suggestion:

```
{% set brands = [] %}
{% for car in cars %}
    {% if car not in brands %}
        {% set brands = brands|merge([car]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for brand in brands %}
   {{ brand }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also I'll take *bartek*'s comment into consideration next time. This was one off.

Answer (score 1):

I have other solution for arrays in loop.
This solution is letting you to make arrays like PHP:

```
$my_array[] = array('key_1' => $value1, 'key_2' => $value_2);
```

in this case:

```
{% set cars_details = [] %}
{% for car in cars %}
     <!-- This is the line of code that does the magic -->
    {% set car = car|merge({(loop.index0) : {'color': car.color, 'year': car.year} }) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ car|dump }}
```

Comment: Have you revised your code to check if it is working? It is more confusing than solving problem.

Comment: @Vishal Kumar Sahu You'r right, I will have to recheck my answer.

Comment: I like how it creates a very specific array! Thanks!