# Twig Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, for-loop, twig

This is probably relatively easy to do, but I'm new to twig and I'm frustrated.

I'm adapting code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24058447

the array is made in PHP through this format:

```
$link[] = array(
       'link' => 'http://example.org',
       'title' => 'Link Title',
       'display' => 'Text to display',
);
```

Then through twig, I add html to it, before imploding:

```
    <ul class="conr">
        <li><span>{{ lang_common['Topic searches'] }} 
        {% set info = [] %}
        {% for status in status_info %}
            {% set info = info|merge(['<a href="{{ status[\'link\'] }}" title="{{ status[\'title\'] }}">{{ status[\'display\'] }}</a>']) %}
        {% endfor %}

        {{ [info]|join(' | ') }}
    </ul>
```

But I'm getting:

> Errno [8] Array to string conversion in
>   F:\localhost\www\twig\include\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php on line 832

It's fixed when I remove this line, but does not display:

```
{{ [info]|join(' | ') }}
```

Any ideas how I can implode this properly?

** update **

Using Twig's dump function it returns nothing. It seems it's not even loading it into the array in the first place. How can I load info into a new array.

Comment: if you're reading this in 2023, [`join`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/join.html) supports two parameters: `glue`, `and` ("_`and`: The separator for the last pair of input items [...] The `and` argument was added in Twig 1.37._")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't really be building complex data structures inside of Twig templates. You can achieve the desired result in a more idiomatic and readable way like this:

```
{% for status in status_info %}
    <a href="{{ status.link }}" title="{{ status.title }}">{{ status.display }}</a>
    {% if not loop.last %}|{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem is though imploding it. I need each element separated by an ' | ' but when I manually do this there is one extra "|" on the right side of the page.

That's the only way I can think of to get only the needed amount.

Comment: Uhm... that's what ***`if not loop.last`*** is supposed to prevent...!?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'd never heard of that. I'm pretty new to Twig.

Answer (score 60):

info is an array, so you should simple write

```
{{ info|join(', ') }}
```

to display your info array.

[info] is a array with one value : the array info.

Comment: NB : Only working with values in case of associative array

Comment: @Delphine If you want to join the keys of an associative array you could pass the array through the `keys` filter first, i.e.

`{{ info | keys | join(', ') }}`

Answer (score 13):

You can user json_encode for serialize array as strig, then show pretty - build in twig

```
    {{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}
```

Comment: Please explain that further - what does your code do? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from that code

Comment: This is the best answer, because it'll convert the whole structure into a string, whereas `join` will fail if the variable is a nested array (e.g. try `['a', ['b'] ]`). Useful for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

if need associative array:

```
{{info|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))|raw}}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: sorry but ['TEXT'] is not a pretty :D